# Why does my code work on some sites but not in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am writing this code on Netbeans and I am hit with an error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean on line 44.

I wrote this code on two websites and it runs with no problems but on NetBeans I get this error.

I am trying to get this output

Enter three integers: 
 1 4 0
State of choices: 
user made firstchoice (1)
user made secondchoice (4)
number of choices = 2

and this output

Enter three integers: 
 7 5 7
State of choices: 
user made firstchoice (7)
user made secondchoice (5)
user made thirdchoice (7)
number of choices = 3

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Teacher's Copy");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter three integers: ");
int firstchoice = input.nextInt();
int secondchoice = input.nextInt();
int thirdchoice = input.nextInt();


if (firstchoice == 0)
System.out.println("State of choices: \n" +
"no choices made yet");

else if (secondchoice == 0)
System.out.println("State of choices: \n" +
"user made firstchoice ( " +firstchoice + ") \n" + 
"number of choices = 1");

if (thirdchoice == 0)
System.out.println("State of choices: \n" + 
"user made firstchoice (" + firstchoice + ")\n" +
"user made secondchoice (" + secondchoice + ")\n" +
"number of choices = 2"); 

System.out.println("State of choices: \n" + 
"user made firstchoice (" + firstchoice + ")\n" +
"user made secondchoice (" + secondchoice + ")\n" +
"user made thirdchoice (" + thirdchoice + ")\n" +
"number of choices = 3");

  }


}
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Which line of code in your example above is line 44?

Comment: Is it possible you have previously compiled code?  I don't use Netbeans, but Eclipse has the option of `Project -> Clean` to remove the compiled code and force it to recompile, I assume Netbeans has a similar option, perhaps try that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely correct. Probably, when you are trying to copy the code, the Netbeans is messing up with yo